# return false in js not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I know that this question has already been asked many times but it's hard for me to understand that why `return false` is not working in my code. I'm expecting that when user leaves a feild blank, JS should stop form posting.
Here's my code:
HTML:

```
<form name="MyForm" method="post" action="">
<div class="span-5">
<label>Select Class</label>
<div>
<select name="selectclass" id="selectclass">
<option value="none">-Select Class-</option>
<?php while($class=mysqli_fetch_array($fetchclass)) 
{ ?>                    
<option value="<?php echo $class['class_name'];?>"
<?php if(isset($_POST['selectclass'])) { if(!strcmp($_POST['selectclass'],$class['class_name'])) echo "selected"; }?>
><?php echo $class['class_name'];?></option>
<?php }?>                    
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="span-5">
        <label>Select View</label>
        <div>
            <select name="selectview" id="selectview">
            <option value="none">-Select-</option>
            <option value="chapter" <?php if(isset($_POST['selectview'])) { if(!strcmp($_POST['selectview'],"chapter")) echo "selected"; }?>>View Chapters</option>
            <option value="topic" <?php if(isset($_POST['selectview'])) { if(!strcmp($_POST['selectview'],"topic")) echo "selected"; }?>>View Topics</option>
            <option value="lecture" <?php if(isset($_POST['selectview'])) { if(!strcmp($_POST['selectview'],"lecture")) echo "selected"; }?>>View Lectures</option>
            <option value="assignment" <?php if(isset($_POST['selectview'])) { if(!strcmp($_POST['selectview'],"assignment")) echo "selected"; }?>>View Assignment</option>
            <option value="evaluationtest" <?php if(isset($_POST['selectview'])) { if(!strcmp($_POST['selectview'],"evaluationtest")) echo "selected"; }?>>View Evaluation Test</option>
            <option value="exampaper" <?php if(isset($_POST['selectview'])) { if(!strcmp($_POST['selectview'],"exampaper")) echo "selected"; }?>>View ExamPapers</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        </div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="View" onclick="checkview()" name="btn" class="blue-btn" />
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkview()
{
    var classname1 = $('#selectclass').val();
    var select_view = $('#selectview').val();
    if (classname1 == 'none' || select_view == 'none')
        {
            alert('Please fill all fields!!');
            return false;
        };
}
</script>
```

When i post this form, it shows me alert (on not selecting any option) and then i expect it not to be posted however it gets posted. I can't find a way to stop this form posting!!

**P.S.**I'm asking a question for first time here. So please don't mind my silly errors.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `onclick="return checkview()"` - you need to return the value from the onclick handler,  but better to use `<form name="MyForm" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return checkview()">`

Comment: `onclick="return checkview()"`

Comment: I prefer submit handler instead `$('#formId').submit(function(){ ....;return false;})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make it as return

```
 <form name="MyForm" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return checkview() ">
```

and at the end make it as

```
 <input type="submit" value="View"  name="btn" class="blue-btn" />
```

`onsubmit` is a js event that is called on submitting a form and based on boolean values it either `doesn't submit` or `submits`

Comment: I did exactly as you mentioned. It gave me HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found and **return checkview()** has been added to the URL of the page. What i've done wrong?

Comment: that is because you have no action on your form..@TusharShukla i edited it..check it now

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot ! @ Danyal Sandeelo

Comment: @TusharShukla welcome :_)